# How to append a Google+1 script

Tags: jquery, google-plus

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/psuP3/) code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<a id="linkGoogle" href="javascript:void;">Show Second Google+1</a><br /><br />

<div id="divGoogle1">
    1° Google+1 : <g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
</div>

<div id="divGoogle2">
    2° Google+1 : 
</div>
```

and I'd like, when I click to the link, append another Google+1 :

```
$('#linkGoogle').click(function () {
    $('#divGoogle2').append("<g:plusone size='medium'></g:plusone>");
});
```

but, of course, it is not "rendered/executed" by *plutone.js* when I append it.

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try
`$('#linkGoogle').live('click', function() {
  $('#divGoogle2').append("<g:plusone size='medium'></g:plusone>");
});`

Comment: Yes (now) and it doesnt works http://jsfiddle.net/psuP3/1/

Comment: just out curiosity, what do you want to add another plus one button ?

Comment: is on another place of the website, but on the same page! :)

Answer (score 0):

simple!

```
$('#linkGoogle').click(function () {
   $('#divGoogle2').append("<g:plusone size='medium'></g:plusone>");
   gapi.plusone.go();   
});
```